# What is the fastest/easiest way to denormalize this heirarchical table into a flat table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, hierarchical-data

I have the following hierarchical table:

```
Table Category:
CategoryId, ParentCategoryId, CategoryName
1, null, SomeRoot
2, 1, SomeChild
3, 2, SomeGrandchild
4, 3, SomeGreatGrandchild
```

(note this sample data doesn't include a leaf on an earlier node than level 4, but that is possible). The data will never go deeper than level 4, if that is relevant.  I'd like to transform/pivot it to this fixed 4 level display

```
CatId, Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4
1, SomeRoot, null, null, null
2, SomeRoot, SomeChild, null, null
3, SomeRoot, SomeChild, SomeGrandchild, null
4, SomeRoot, SomeChild, SomeGrandchild, SomeGreatGrandchild
```

I've done left outer joining to the category table 4 times, and built a huge case statement for detecting the level to use for the ID field, but that doesn't include the null rows....  Any ideas?  HELP!

Comment: You need to tell us whether the data will always have <X number of levels or if it can be infinitely recursive.

Comment: @jcollum Updated Q: The data will never go deeper than level 4, if that is relevant.

Comment: If it has unknown levels of recursion you want to use a CTE. For known and small levels of recursion I hear a CTE has too much overhead so a subquery is better.

Comment: No CTE needed here since it's always just 4.  But whatever works is best!  No big performance required on transformation here.  I'm denormalizing the data for efficient reads on the front end.  If it takes a minute to build I don't care.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this probably isn't the most efficient query, but it is the easiest to code:

```
declare @YourTable table (CategoryId int primary key, ParentCategoryId int , CategoryName varchar(50))

INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (1, null, 'SomeRoot')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (2, 1, 'SomeChild')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (3, 2, 'SomeGrandchild')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (4, 3, 'SomeGreatGrandchild')

INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (10, null, 'X_SomeRoot')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (20, 10, 'X_SomeChild')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (30, 20, 'X_SomeGrandchild')


Select
    c1.CategoryId, c1.CategoryName, c2.CategoryName, c3.CategoryName, c4.CategoryName
    From @YourTable          c1
        INNER JOIN @YourTable c2 On c1.CategoryId = c2.ParentCategoryId
        INNER JOIN @YourTable c3 On c2.CategoryId = c3.ParentCategoryId
        INNER JOIN @YourTable c4 On c3.CategoryId = c4.ParentCategoryId
    WHERE c1.ParentCategoryId IS NULL 
UNION
Select
    c1.CategoryId, c1.CategoryName, c2.CategoryName, c3.CategoryName, NULL
    From @YourTable          c1
        INNER JOIN @YourTable c2 On c1.CategoryId = c2.ParentCategoryId
        INNER JOIN @YourTable c3 On c2.CategoryId = c3.ParentCategoryId
    WHERE c1.ParentCategoryId IS NULL
UNION
Select
    c1.CategoryId, c1.CategoryName, c2.CategoryName, NULL, NULL
    From @YourTable          c1
        INNER JOIN @YourTable c2 On c1.CategoryId = c2.ParentCategoryId
    WHERE c1.ParentCategoryId IS NULL
UNION
Select
    c1.CategoryId, c1.CategoryName, NULL, NULL, NULL
    From @YourTable          c1
    WHERE c1.ParentCategoryId IS NULL
ORDER BY 2,3,4,5
```

OUTPUT:

```
SortB CategoryId  CategoryName CategoryName  CategoryName      CategoryName
----- ----------- ------------ ------------- ----------------- --------------------
1     1           SomeRoot     NULL          NULL              NULL
2     1           SomeRoot     SomeChild     NULL              NULL
3     1           SomeRoot     SomeChild     SomeGrandchild    NULL
4     1           SomeRoot     SomeChild     SomeGrandchild    SomeGreatGrandchild
1     10          X_SomeRoot   NULL          NULL              NULL
2     10          X_SomeRoot   X_SomeChild   NULL              NULL
3     10          X_SomeRoot   X_SomeChild   X_SomeGrandchild  NULL

(7 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  Select C.CatId, C.Name, PC.Name, GP.Name, GGP.Name
  From Category C
    Left Join Category PC On PC.CatId = C.ParentCategoryId
    Left Join Category GP On GP .CatId = PC.ParentCategoryId
    Left Join Category GGP On GGP .CatId = GP.ParentCategoryId
```

Based on yr comment, if you write a UDF as follows:

```
Create Function CatParentNames
( @CatId Integer )
Returns varchar(1000)
AS
Begin
     Declare @outVal VarChar(1000)
     Declare @ParId Integer
     Select @ParId = ParentCategoryId, @outVal = Name
     From Category 
     Where CatId = @CatId
     While Exists(Select * From Category 
                  Where CatId = @ParId)
        Begin
           Select @ParId = ParentCategoryId, 
                 @outVal = Name + ', ' + @outVal
           From Category 
           Where CatId = @ParId
        End

 Return @outVal

End
```

then, write your sql as follows:

```
Select CatId, dbo.CatParentNames(CatId)
From Category
Where ParentCategoryId Is Not Null
```

Comment: I had that originally - but with a "where C.parentcategoryid is null" to keep it going off the root.  However, it would in this example above only return 1 result.  Also, the Id would be the root's

Comment: try it without the where clause?  Cause that where clause WOULD restrict it to the only one root record (that's the only one with null parentCatId)

Comment: The way I've written it it should return every row in the Category table, cause there's no where clause, and the joins are all outer joins....

Comment: It will not output the data as written in my question.  For Id 2 it will output 2, SomeChild, null, null, null.  For Id 3 it will output 3, SomeGrandchild, null, null, null.  Both are wrong.

Comment: So you only want one record in the output for each Child record, not for the root recordz? in your sample output, every row has someroot as value of name1, This makes me suspect you want CatId, and then the names of all the objects in that objects heiarchy. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select a.CategoryId as CatId, 
a.CategoryName as Name1, 
cast(null as varchar(20)) as Name2, 
cast(null as varchar(20)) as Name3,
cast(null as varchar(20)) as Name4
from @YourTable a
where a.ParentCategoryId is null

union all

select b.CategoryId, 
a.CategoryName, 
b.CategoryName,
null,
null
from @YourTable a
inner join @YourTable b
on a.CategoryId = b.ParentCategoryId
where a.ParentCategoryId is null


union all

select c.CategoryId, 
a.CategoryName, 
b.CategoryName, 
c.CategoryName, 
null
from @YourTable a
inner join @YourTable b
on a.CategoryId = b.ParentCategoryId
inner join @YourTable c
on b.CategoryId = c.ParentCategoryId
where a.ParentCategoryId is null

union all 

select d.CategoryId, 
a.CategoryName, 
b.CategoryName, 
c.CategoryName, 
d.CategoryName
from @YourTable a
inner join @YourTable b
on a.CategoryId = b.ParentCategoryId
inner join @YourTable c
on b.CategoryId = c.ParentCategoryId
inner join @YourTable d
on c.CategoryId = d.ParentCategoryId
order by 2, 3, 4, 5
```

But that is not the way to build it if you are going to use it with a multi-column TreeView that looks like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [digitaltools.com](http://www.digitaltools.com/images/GVT.jpg))</sub>

More can be found [here.](http://www.digitaltools.com/gvt.aspx)

Comment: you need to add an extra column to the first query, so all have the same number of columns, and a sort would help

Comment: when I run it using my test table and data I only get rows for the 1st and last of each "set"

Comment: You're right, it is fixed now and now uses the @YourTable table from the other post.